# Proving two expressions are Coprime

Tags: modular-arithmetic, coprime

How would I prove $3y + 2$ and $3y-1$ are coprime. I know that the highest common factor of these two expressions will divide the difference between the numbers, so it will be a factor of 3, so either 1 or 3.

Is it because $3y + 2$ and $3y-1$ aren’t multiples of 3 so it must be 1?

Cheers.

Comment: No, you have to use that a common divisor would also divide the difference , which is $3$ , so we have to check only $1$ and $3$. $3$ cannot be a common divisor , so the gcd must be $1$.

Comment: $(3n+2;3n-1)=(3n+2;3)=1$-euclidean algorithm

Comment: $\gcd(3n+2,3n-1)=\gcd(3n+2,3)=\gcd(2,3)=1$.

Comment: @DietrichBurde where does the 3 come from? I tried using the Euclidean algorithm that 3n + 2 = 3(n) + 2

Comment: Oh, 3 is the difference

Comment: 3 can’t be the common divisor since they aren’t multiples of 3?

Comment: **Or:** $\bmod\, \underbrace{\color{#c00}{3y-1}\!:\,\ \color{#c00}{3y}+2\equiv \color{#c00}1+2}_{\textstyle \color{#c00}{3y\equiv 1}}\equiv y^{-1}\,$ is invertible, so they're coprime. $\ \ $

Comment: @Peter So because a common divisor divides the difference that is 1 or 3, but since both expressions are clearly not multiples of 3, the hcf must be 1?

Comment: Almost : The difference is $3$ and the gcd must divide it , so the gcd must be $1$ or $3$ , but it cannot be $3$ because the numbers are no multiple of $3$.

Comment: Okay thanks for clearing it up. I was using this fact to prove that there were no solutions to a diophantine equation, as x^4 was equal to the expression I gave. Because the expression I gave was coprime, and x^4 is a perfect power of 4, 3y +2 and 3y - 1 must be perfect powers of 4. And there are no powers of 4 which differ by 3, so no solutions.